# I can't connect with method

Tags: java, android

why can't I contact the second page

This is inside my **Adapter**

```
holder.btn_filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (position == 1)
                {
                    ShowMessages showMessages = new ShowMessages();
                    showMessages.message();
                }

   }}
```

**Home Activity**

```
public class ShowMessages extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_messages);


}
public void message()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hola", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //or set text or change adapter etc...
    }
}
```

When called with message() inside adapter comes out of the application why ?

Comment: Show your log info .

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxKiY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that ShowMessages is an activity here and when you try to instantiate an activity through new, the context is null. Always use intents to create new activities. If you want to trigger some method in the activity from the adapter, pass the activity to the adapter as the constructor argument, cache it in the adapter and then use it to call message().

Something like this would do:

ShowMessages.java - adapter initialization in activity:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
```

MyAdapter.java:

```
private Activity activity;

MyAdapter(ShowMessages activity) {
  this.activity = activity;
}
```

And then in your adapter:

```
holder.btn_filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (position == 1)
                {
                    activity.message();
                }

   }}
```

Also, you are being memory efficient here, as you are not instantiating a new activity for every click at position 1.